# Error C2039 in boost class with Boost 1.34.1 on VC6

Tags: c++, boost, visual-c++-6

Some history:
I originally wanted to use boost for ASIO, but then found that ASIO won't work with VC++ 6.0 (which is a requirement).  While incorporating boost, I found use for Multi_Index_Container and Signals.  Aftering finding that ASIO was not compatible, I downgraded boost to version 1.34.1 so that it would support VC6.  Now I'm trying to iron out all of the other compile errors.

At first, I had this code and error:
I am trying to use Boost Multi_Index from build 1.34.1 to set up a
collection of structs.  This Multi Index container will have 2 unique keys
(ID and Name), since I have to be able to search it with either key.  I
made the compiler-specific corrections for VC++ 6.0 SP5:

```
boost::multi_index::multi_index_container
member_offset<A,int,offsetof(A,x)>
```

My complete declaration is:

```
enum RESPONSE_CODES
{
    Pass = 200,
    Fail = 201,
    Hex = 202,
    Decimal = 203,
    String = 204,
    Help = 205,
    None = 255
}

struct PDCUTestMessage
{
    string name;
    char id;
    RESPONSE_CODES responseType;
    int numberOfParameters;
    string errorString;
    vector<char> response;
    string param1Name;
    string param2Name;
    string param3Name;
    string param4Name;
    string param5Name;
    boost::function2<bool, vector<char>, PDCUTestMessage &> process;

    // constructors not listed
};

struct ID();
struct Name();

typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
    PDCUTestMessage,
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
        boost::multi_index::tag<ID>,
        boost::multi_index::member_offset<PDCUTestMessage, char, offsetof(PDCUTestMessage, id)> >,
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
        boost::multi_index::tag<Name>,
        boost::multi_index::member_offset<PDCUTestMessage, string, offsetof(PDCUTestMessage, name)> >
    >
> PDCUMessageList;
```

Later, I attempt to set up indicies for both of these keys, according to
VC++ 6.0 compiler-specific syntax to bypass the Get/Tag issue:

```
typedef index<PDCUMessageList, ID>::type IDIndex;
typedef index<PDCUMessageList, Name>::type NameIndex;
```

using the above code, I got the following error:

error C2039: 'type': is not a member of "global namespace" referencing the two typedef lines above.

This issue I fixed by clarifying the namespaces:

```
typedef boost::multi_index::index<PDCUMessageList, ID>::type IDIndex;
typedef boost::multi_index::index<PDCUMessageList, Name>::type NameIndex;
```

Now I've got another error occuring in one of the boost classes: 
lambda_traits.hpp.  I'm not explicitly using lambda_traits, so it must be 
multi_index that is using it.  Here's the error and location:

C2039: 'access_traits': is not a member of 'tuples'

line 106 in lambda_traits:

```
104  template<int N, class T> struct tuple_element_as_reference {
105    typedef typename
106      boost::tuples::access_traits<
107        typename boost::tuples::element<N, T>::type
108      >::non_const_type type;
109  };
```

Anyone have any ideas how to get past this latest error?

Comment: You need to upgrade your compiler- it's not even C++98 compliant.

Comment: How can you tell?  The VC++ directories I'm pointing to in my design environment are VC98 and msdev98.  As far as I know, I am C++98 compliant.  How do I verify that?

Comment: VC++ 6.0 came out a month after the C++98 standard was finalized, and it is quite notorious for using many pre-standard constructs and syntax. The first version of VC++ to have any decent level of standard support is VC++ 8.0 (though 7.1 at least fixed some template weirdness). Whoever's forcing you to use VC++ 6.0 is a sadist. ;-]

Comment: It is not a person that is forcing the requirement, but the target hardware and software, and my desired approach.  I am a government programmer developing for a target system whose configuration is set to Windows NT4 and cannot be changed.  The final product is ideally an upgraded executable that can be copied to the target hardware in place of the existing version with no additional changes needed to the system.  The current exe is written in VC6 with MFC.  If you can suggest another way of using C++ with Boost on Windows NT4 with no additional installtion, I'm all ears :o)

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, template parsing is just awkward in VC6.
Try to simplify dependent types as much as you can. For example:

```
template<int N, class T> struct tuple_element_as_reference {
  typedef typename boost::tuples::element<N, T>
     tuples_element_t;

  typedef typename tuples_element_t::type
     tuples_element_type_t;

  typedef typename boost::tuples::access_traits<
     tuples_element_type_t
  >
     tuples_access_traits_t;

  typedef typename tuples_access_traits_t::non_const_type
     type;
};
```

Comment: I'm assuming, though, that the cause is something in my code.  The error couldn't have originated in a boost class, as version 1.34.1 has been compiled and tested successfully for VC6, right?  I probably shouldn't be altering the actual boost classes...

Comment: Probably. Are you sure that your ID and Name definitions are correct?

Comment: I edited my original post to include the code for struct PDCUTestMessage and an enum that is a member of the struct.  I'm pretty sure my definitions are correct, but it's probably best to post them anyway.